# AngularJS: Popout view similar to JIRA

Tags: angularjs, popup

I am trying to get a popup window that displays a view on top of my main view.  I basically want to use the idea that many project management applications use, such as VersionOne and JIRA.  In JIRA, under an epic, there is a "Create issue in epic" feature that gives you a popup window that is essentially a form.  I am just trying to get the popup window (same size, displays data) to work with AngularJS.

A snippet from my main view where I am linking to the detailed view.  I assume the magic will happen in the `<a>` tag.:

```
<h6 data-toggle="popover" data-placement="top" data-content="commands">
    <a href="partials/instance-view.html">
        {{instance.name}}
    </a>
</h6>
```

The secondary view is just displayed in the `instance-view.html` file.  I don't think the `<h6>` tag is messing anything up, but I could be wrong.  Also, I know that since I am trying to display a link inside a popover tag, the popover won't work.  I can always fix that later.

Answer (score 0):

Assume you are using bootstrap?

If so, have you tried using the bootstrap popover plug-in inside your  tag rather than your ?

i.e. ...

```
<h6>
    <a href="partials/instance-view.html" title="Header" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="top" data-content="commands">{{instance.name}}</a>
</h6>
```

Comment: That still just links to another page.  The page doesn't actually popup like I want it to.

Answer (score 0):

Modals should be used for what is trying to be achieved.  In particular, Bootstrap Modals.